# When will WASM runtime be integrated into Envoy proxy

Tags: webassembly, envoyproxy

It looks like the WebAssembly/WASM runtime is not integrated into the Envoy proxy by default up to v1.15.0. When will the envoyproxy/envoy-wasm project be fully merged into envoyproxy/envoy.

I tried to check out the envoyproxy/envoy-wasm project after checking out the repo. Having trouble build it using `bazel build`. Seeing a bunch of error not sure how to resolve. Now I am stuck:

```
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/c2e985b1122c602a6e8f21970f55e80d/external/bazel_toolchains/rules/rbe_repo/version_check.bzl:68:14: 
Current running Bazel is ahead of bazel-toolchains repo. Please update your pin to bazel-toolchains repo in your WORKSPACE file.
```

Answer (score 1):

It was done on October 9, 2020 in https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/pull/12546.